# Terraform azure-remove subcription details from output

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I declared security group in following way:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "wan" {
  count               = "${var.enable_wan_subnet ? 1 : 0}"
  provider            = "azurerm.base"
  name                = "${format("%s-%s", var.environment_name, "WAN-Subnet-Security-Group")}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.this.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.this.name}"

tags = "${
    merge(map("Name", format("%s-%s-%s",var.environment_name,"WAN-Subnets", "Security-Group")), 
    var.tags_global, 
    var.tags_module)
    }"
}
```

and created output for that security group:

```
output "security_groups_id_wan" {
  value = "${azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id}"

  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
}
```

In output i'm getting

**Actual output**

```
security_groups_id_wan = [
    /subscriptions/111-222-333-4445/resourceGroups/default_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DF-DTAP-WAN-Subnet-Security-Group
]
```

How, from output, to remove all except resource name (DF-DTAP-WAN-Subnet-Security-Group)

**Desired output:**

```
security_groups_id_wan = [
   DF-DTAP-WAN-Subnet-Security-Group
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the Terraform functions and change the output value like this:

```
output "security_groups_id_wan" {
  value = "${slice(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id), length(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id))-1, length(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id)))}"

  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
}
```

With the functions, you can output every resource as you need. For more details, see [Terraform Supported built-in functions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#supported-built-in-functions).

**Update**

The test with an existing NSG through the Terraform data and the template here:

```
data "azurerm_network_security_group" "test" {
        name = "azureUbuntu18-nsg"
        resource_group_name = "charles"
}

output "substring" {
        value = "${slice(split("/",data.azurerm_network_security_group.test.id), length(split("/",data.azurerm_network_security_group.test.id))-1, length(split("/",data.azurerm_network_security_group.test.id)))}"
}
```

The screenshot of the result here:

[image]

Comment: thanks but getting this: ` * output.subnets_id_wan: At column 9, line 1: split: argument 2 should be type string, got type list in:

${slice(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id), length(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id))-1, length(split("/",azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id)))}`

Comment: The second parameter of the function split() should be a string. And if you create serial NSGs, the id would be an array. You use an exact id.

Comment: thanks @Charles Xu, i had to convert list to string first

Comment: if using slice in output then getting azurerm_network_security_group doesn't have attribute id

Comment: The slice just selects some elements from a list for you.

Comment: ok, thanks, so, to pass resources from one module to another i can't use slice, must use "standard" output syntax ?,all works fine without slice.

Comment: yes, you can get the attribute id without any function through the resource.

Answer (score 0):

You built that name yourself with `"${format("%s-%s", var.environment_name, "WAN-Subnet-Security-Group")}"` so why not just output that?

To save repeating yourself you could put that in a local and refer to it in both the resource and the output:

```
locals {
  security_group_name = "${format("%s-%s", var.environment_name, "WAN-Subnet-Security-Group")}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "wan" {
  count               = "${var.enable_wan_subnet ? 1 : 0}"
  provider            = "azurerm.base"
  name                = "${local.security_group_name}"
  # ...
}

output "security_groups_id_wan" {
  value = "${local.security_group_name}"
}
```

Note that you also didn't need the `depends_on` because a) it's an output, it happens at the end of things anyway and b) you already have an implicit dependency on that resource because you used an interpolation that included the resource.

You can read more about Terraform dependencies via the [Hashicorp Learn platform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html#implicit-and-explicit-dependencies).

Comment: i tried it and it works, but i have multiple resources (not only security group), and i need for every resource to declare different variable (locals), is there any more elegant way ?

Comment: You should consider asking a separate question that adds that extra constraint and show why this answer doesn't work for your second question with your extra constraint, linking to this one for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Charles Xu's answer:Had to convert list to string first

```
output "subnets_id_wan" {

  value = "${slice(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id)), length(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id)))-1, length(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id))))}"



  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
}
```